# zsh command not found issue

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I installed sublime text 2 and created a symlink to it and placed it in ~/bin. I added ~/bin to PATH variable in ~/.zshrc.

If I try to execute subl (sublime's symlink), I get:

```
zsh: command not found: subl
```

But if I execute ~/bin/subl, it works correctly.

Echoing the PATH shows that ~/bin is in the PATH variable.:

```
~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Any idea what can cause the command not found issue?

Comment: How did you set `PATH`? Adding `~/bin` should work, but echoing `$PATH` should show the tilde replaced by your actual home directory.

Comment: I added ~/bin to PATH variable directly in my .zshrc file. Echoing $PATH doesn't show the expanded version for some reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

bash interprets `~` in PATH, but most shells do not.

Use `$HOME` instead.

Comment: `zsh` allows `~` as well, but apparently there was a glitch in adding `~`.

Comment: @chepner In your case you probably expanded the `~` before adding it to the PATH, e.g. with `PATH=~/bin:$PATH`. If you do `PATH="~/bin:$PATH"` or otherwise get a literal tilde into PATH, it's not interpretted.

Comment: Right, that's what I alluded to in my comment on the question; I should have been clearer. (For full disclosure, I actually use something like `path=(~/bin $path)`, but the same principle applies.)